# Why does Sublime highlight "model" as a keyword for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sublimetext2

I have a variable called *model* in my Ruby on Rails app and for some reason Sublime highlights it as a special keyword, however I'm not sure why.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Mine does that as well. I think that it is just an oversight of sublimetext2. However, `model` is not on the reserved words list.